# JS Ajax function not setting variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax function

```
  function get_country(request_term) {
    var country_list = '';
    $.ajax({
      url   : "activity/get_country", 
      type  : "POST",
      cache : false,
      data  : {
        request_term : request_term
      },
      success : function(data) {
        if(data != '') {
          country_list = $.parseJSON(data);
          alert(country_list);               ----> Got value here
        }
      }
    });
    alert(country_list);                     ----> Not getting value here
    return country_list;
  }
```

the problem is, i'm getting the data in the success function, but unable to return it from the main function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Answer (score 1):

Because ajax is asynchronous, you can't know when the `success` function will complete (or if it will *ever* complete).  Therefore any code that requires the result of the ajax call must depend on the ajax callback too.

jQuery makes it very easy to bind additional callbacks.

```
return $.ajax({ /* rest of your code */

get_country(request_term).done(function (data) {
    //are you sure JSON isn't returned already?
    country_list = $.parseJSON(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by making async as false. But it is not a recommented way.

This code will return country_list

```
function get_country(request_term) {
var country_list = '';
$.ajax({
  url   : "activity/get_country", 
  type  : "POST",
  cache : false,
  async : false,
  data  : {
    request_term : request_term
  },
  success : function(data) {
    if(data != '') {
      country_list = $.parseJSON(data);
      alert(country_list);               
    }
  }
});
alert(country_list);                     
return country_list;
```

}

Comment: @DBK please reffer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517403/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-using-synchronous-ajax-call