# Elements prepended using jQuery .get() while looping through array are loaded in different order on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I want to show a subsection of some projects on my webpage. I have an array of project names and some corresponding data in html files, like in the example below. I have a button with some preview-content in it, and if a user clicks on that it opens up the full container with all the project details.

To do this I though to loop through a sliced array in reverse and prepend the code to a div element on my webpage. The content often loads fine, but sometimes when I refresh the page it will display the previews in a different order than as defined in the array. Also, sometimes "previewtitle" and "previewcontent" return undefined, but not all the time. What am I doing wrong here?

I want to prepend the projects dynamically in the same order on every refresh.

```
var $projectNames = [ "coolprojecthere", "andanotherone", "moreprojects", "lastone" ];
```

projects/coolprojecthere.html looks like this:

```
<div id="title">Project title here</div>
<div id="content">Content html here</div>
```

projects/previews/coolprojecthere.html looks like this:

```
<div id="title">Project title here</div>
<div id="content">Content text here</div>
```

I loop through them like this to prepend them:

```
$projectNames = $projectNames.slice(0, 7);
    $.each($projectNames.reverse(), function (index, projectname) {
        var previewtitle, previewcontent;
        $.get("projects/previews/" + projectname + ".html", function (prevdata) {
            previewtitle = $(prevdata).filter('#title').text();
            previewcontent = $(prevdata).filter('#content').text();
        });
        $.get("projects/" + projectname + ".html", function (data) {
            var project = "<section id=\"project\" class=\"\"> \
                                        <t>" + previewtitle + "</t><br /> \
                                        <p>" + previewcontent + "</p> \
                                </div> \
                                <div class=\"content\"> \
                                    <h5>" + $(data).filter('#title').text() + "</h5> \
                                    <div class=\"content-container\">"
                                        + $(data).filter('#content').html() +
                                    "</div> \
                                </div> \
                            </section>"
            $('#main-container').prepend(project);
        });
```

Comment: Ajax is **asynchronous**. You are making multiple requests at the same time and the responses may return in any order. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) you must specify `async` option to be set to `false` to get a synchronous AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'projects/previews/" + projectname + ".html', 
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
     // your code here
    }
});
```

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false.

Otherwise, you could also do the *jQuery's AJAX* setup, and set it in synchronous mode by calling once (above your initial code):

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

It will perform all your further AJAX calls in *synchronous mode*. You can continue using  `jQuery.get();` method as you did before.

> *Note:* Please read [*Felix Kling*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23847803/1455661)'s answer, about when synchronous calls might be a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was struggling with this for a while now and I had no idea why it kept changing the order.

Comment: You should note that making a synchronous call is a bad idea in must cases, *especially* when multiple calls are involved. The browser will become unusable during the duration of all the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Making the Ajax calls synchronous [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6517403/218196). Instead, you should *chain* and nest them, so that each one is executed after each other.

Lets organize your code a little more, using [**promises**](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/):

```
function getPreviewData(projectName) {
  return $.get(
    "projects/previews/" + projectname + ".html"
  ).then(function(prevdata) {
    return {
      title: $(prevdata).filter('#title').text(), 
      content:  $(prevdata).filter('#content').text()
    };
  );
}

function getProjectHTML(projectName, previewTitle, previewContent) {
  return $.get("projects/" + projectname + ".html").then(function (data) {
    // ...
  });
}

$projectNames = $projectNames.slice(0, 7);
var head = new $.Deferred();
var chain = head.promise();

$.each($projectNames.reverse(), function (index, projectName) {
  chain = chain.then(function() {
    return getPreviewData(projectName).then(function(previewData) {
      return getProjectHTML(projectName, previewData.title,  previewData.content);
    });
  });
});

head.resolve();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've updated my code accordingly. Though I think the bit `var chain = chain.promise();` should be `var chain = head.promise();` right?

Comment: Yep... tossed some variable names around and missed that one.