# ajax post in for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use ajax post to post current i value to other php page in loop and get the same i value from that php page. But, i value incremented by 1 before posted. This line `console.log(data);`  output `2,..,100,1` .I don't understand why it happen so. The expected output is `1,..,100`.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '2.php',   
    data: { 'id': i }   ,
    success: function(data) {                                                                           
    //console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

2.php

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['id'];
?>
```

Comment: Add `exit();` right after your `echo $_POST['id'];` to make sure the output is flushed

Comment: Because  $.ajax is async..

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé even if $.ajax is async, it would at least print out the test values in order sometimes, not all the time

Comment: Is the responses order always the same ? And is it 2,3,4,5...98,99,100,1 ?

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé,it print in that order every time.

Comment: @Ahmad,exit() does not make any difference.

Comment: I tried the exact code from OP, locally (ubuntu,apache) and I could not reproduce the issue. The order of responses is slightly different each time, most of the time 1 is logged first... Can you confirm using your browser console (network tab), that the first  request sent is the one with id=1, and that it is also the last one to finish ?

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé, i checked the first request sent in network tab. It was 1. When get back the value in ajax success, it become 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the ajax call inside a new function then invoke the function into the loop.

Also add async:false in you ajax request. It will send the ajax request synchronously waiting for the previous request to finish and then sending the next request.

Something like

```
function func() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        makeRequest(i);
    }
}

function makeRequest(i) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '2.php',
        data: {
            'id': i
        },
        async:false,
        success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data);

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: set `async:false` able to print output in correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

[Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

[This is called closure inside loop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

```
for(i=1;i<=100; i++) {
  (function(index){
      $.ajax({
            type    :'POST',
            url     :'2.php',   
            data    :{'id':index}   ,
            success :function(data)
            {                                                                          
               //console.log(data);
            }
     });

    })(i);
}
```

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, I tried. It does not output any value

Comment: @Premlatha I have solved the issue. Please have a look at.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare,It output the value not in order. Set `async:false` solve order issue. But load slower.

Comment: @Premlatha Yes. Output will not be in the order. Because this is async call.

Comment: @Premlatha `async:false` will be synchronous call. It will wait for the next iteration until the previous response not received. This approach will solve order issue, but due to the synchronous call, it will be very slow.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare,please add `async:false` in your answer so that I could upvote the answer.

Comment: @Premlatha Actually `async:false` is not a recommended way. We can take another approach for order.

Comment: @Premlatha see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517403/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-using-synchronous-ajax-call

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, thanks for link. I understand that `Synchronous call is not recommended as it blocks the page until the response is received`. And `Asynchronous call  will continue to process next id if previous result not ready and will execute that previous result when it is ready.But, It do process all the id.` In my case, I am doing this to show progress on progressbar. So, I wish to do in order so that I can stop the progress bar when it stuck at some id. If  Asynchronous, we do not know where it stuck.

Comment: @Premlatha It can be possible in asynchronous as well. You can store the response from each request into the array and you can check completion status, as you know how many are completed out of 100.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, how to store response in ajax success to array and process it outside of ajax?